# Как узнать количество входов пользователя в андроид приложение?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-analytics

Собираю статистику пользователя, чтобы выдавать ему некоторую информацию. Как мне получить сколько раз пользователь открывал мое андроид приложение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте класс производный от `Application`

```
public class App extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // тут инкрементируйте счётчик запусков с помощью SharedPreferences
    }

}
```

И не забудьте зарегистрировать класс в манифесте, написав в тегe `application`:

```
android:name=".App" <!-- если App в корне пакета -->
```

Answer (score 5):

Встройте аналитику в свое приложение. Например [Firebase](http://firebase.google.com) от гугла. Там есть разные ивенты, например session_start. Вы сможете увидеть очень много показателей: сколько запусков, сколько пользователей, какой пол и т.д. Очень много разных данных

UPD: А если необходимо только локально собирать инфу:
При каждом запуске инкрементировать переменную в [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences), а когда необходимо доставать ее оттуда.

Comment: В какой момент нужно инкрементировать переменную? Я так понимаю в методах жизненного цикла activity, но тогда как отличить запуска приложения от, например, смены ориентации экрана? if ( savedInstanceState == null )?